# Best way to install PyQt5 for Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pyqt5

I am attempting to install PyQt5 on my Ubuntu box. I have been able to install the packages for Python 3, however,I have code that depends on  pygraphviz which has a hard dependency on Python 2.7.

I was looking through the repos and I see that there is a package for it:

python-pyqt5 (5.3.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1)

So I try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pyqt5
```

SO I downloaded the package and attempted to install manually:

```
sudo dpkg -i python-pyqt5_5.3.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package python-pyqt5.
(Reading database ... 253766 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python-pyqt5_5.3.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-pyqt5 (5.3.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyqt5:
 python-pyqt5 depends on libqt5core5a (>= 5.3.0); however:
  Version of libqt5core5a:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
 python-pyqt5 depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.3.0) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.3.0); however:
  Version of libqt5gui5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
  Package libqt5gui5-gles is not installed.
 python-pyqt5 depends on libqt5help5 (>= 5.3.0); however:
  Version of libqt5help5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1-8build1.
 python-pyqt5 depends on libqt5network5 (>= 5.3.0); however:
  Version of libqt5network5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
 python-pyqt5 depends on libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.3.0); however:
  Version of libqt5printsupport5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
 python-pyqt5 depends on libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.3.0); however:
  Version of libqt5widgets5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
 python-pyqt5 depends on qtbase-abi-5-3-0; however:
  Package qtbase-abi-5-3-0 is not installed.
 python-pyqt5 depen
dpkg: error processing package python-pyqt5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pyqt5
```

I see that I may have some outdated packages I have attempted to update using apt-get update with no results.

I have downloaded source to build; however, I would rather use package management to control dependencies. Is there any advice on how to resolve this using apt?

Thank you for your help!
Joseph

Comment: `apt-get install -f`

Comment: I have attempted this. It appears to be marking python-pyqt5 for removal

Answer (score 2):

I have found my answer for this question here: https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2014-May/034175.html

Basically, it seems that the Python 2 versions of PyQt5 were left out of the Ubuntu 14.04 repos; however, they seem to be included in  14.10.

So, I installed PyQt5 from source which was not without its own woes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080304/issues-with-building-pyqt5-on-ubuntu-14-04

At any rate, I now have PyQt5 installed on my box.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated my answer and also provided a link for the process that I used to get up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to install **Anaconda** and install it using conda

```
conda install pyqt
```